# Why do victims “sustain” injuries?

Tags: meaning

In the phrase *sustain an injury*, the sense of the verb strikes me as out of line with its other senses, most of which can be replaced with either *support* or *continue*.  Can someone suggest a chain of metaphor by which this usage arose?

I would blame it on TV news, but Wiktionary cites an example in Shakespeare.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the sense of *suffer*, and surely you can see how someone would suffer an injury. From [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=sustain):

> c. 1300, "give support to," from stem of Old French *sostenir* "hold up, bear; suffer, endure" (13c.), from Latin *sustinere* "hold up, hold upright; furnish with means of support; bear, undergo, endure," from assimilated form of *sub* "up from below" (see sub-) + *tenere* "to hold," from PIE root **ten*- "to stretch." Meaning "continue, keep up" (an action, etc.) is from early 14c.

Comment: I guess I should be asking this in Latin, then. :(